# Better way of inserting in a map of pointers c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, stl, insert

I have the following structure and a class

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

class myClass
{
    map<int, myStruct*> myMap;
    int i;
    //and few other member variables and functions
    public:
        void doFunc();
}
```

Which is the correct/better way of inserting in to this map provided that the `doFunc()` is called multiple times for one object of `myClass` at a time, with values of `i` ranging from 0-100

```
void myClass::doFunc()
{
    myStruct obj;
    obj.a = 1;
    obj.b = 2;
    obj.c = 3;
    myMap[i] = &obj;
    i++;
}
```

or

```
void myClass::doFunc()
{
    myStruct obj = new myStruct();
    obj->a = 1;
    obj->b = 2;
    obj->c = 3;
    myMap[i] = obj;
    i++;
}
```

provided that the dynamically allocated memory will be cleared in the destructor of `myClass`. Please note that in the actual code, there are a bunch of other member variables as well in `myStruct` so not using a constructor at this point in time. I will be refactoring the code after this confusion is clear.

Comment: The first question back to you need to be: Why are you using pointers to begin with? What problem are they supposed to solve, that normal non-pointer objects can't solve?

Comment: And any decent teaching or learning resource ([book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), class or tutorial) should have taught you why `myMap[i] = &obj` is *wrong*. And depending on your constructor of `myClass`, the usage of `i` might make it wrong as well.

Comment: I also wonder about why you're using a map? The way you add elements seems like you're using it as a kind of vector or array? What is the purpose of the map? What problem is the map itself supposed to solve? Why can't you use a `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: should be `myStruct *obj = new myStruct();` And maintaining a map of owning pointers asks for a trouble

Comment: `map<int, myStruct> myMap;` -- You should have started with this obvious way to have declared and used the map.  Why did you resort to using pointers?  Both of the example code you showed indicates you are not aware of the value-semantics that C++ has.  A simple `myStruct obj;...myMap[i] = obj;` would have done the job.

Comment: `myMap[i] = &obj` -- You are storing the address of a temporary -- you are *not* telling C++ to create a reference and to hold onto it into the map until you dispose of it.  C++ does not work this way.  That temporary goes away when `doFunc` returns.  I believe you saw that the code compiled with no errors, thus fooled into thinking the code "works".  That's the danger of not learning C++ properly -- stuff that compiles with no errors doesn't mean the code at runtime is valid.

Comment: Forget about those other languages you're familiar with, get [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282), and start at the beginning. You can't learn C++ by guessing and trial-and-error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I did start with ```map<int, myStruct> myMap;``` only but storing plain objects would not be memory efficient compared to storing pointers

Comment: @arjungulyani *only but storing plain objects would not be memory efficient compared to storing pointers* -- That is not true.  That pointer has to live somewhere, thus takes up 4 or 8 bytes just by itself.  Plus that pointer must point somewhere valid, an additional `sizeof(myStruct)` bytes.  That is *less* memory efficient than storing just the object.

Comment: About memory efficiency of storing plain objects: "The first rule of optimization is: Don’t do it. The second rule of optimization (for experts only) is: Don’t do it yet."

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie if the temporary gets deleted as soon as the function execution is over then how does this work https://onlinegdb.com/F9IJZu5fQ

Comment: @arjungulyani "completely by accident" and it will stop working if you call a second function inbetween. (a points into stack space that _will_ be overwritten by another function call.)

Comment: Why not use smart pointers? `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<myStruct>>`.

Comment: Unfortunately, for pointers to be "memory efficient" here, you will need to figure out some way to violate multiple fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe. The object of ***each*** pointer to has to exist somewhere, and take up exactly the same amount of memory. An object, no matter where it exists, must use a fixed amount of memory, at least until our entire universe collapses back into a primordial black hole, eons from now. Until then, an object will take up certain amount of memory, and adding more memory for a pointer to it can't make the end result more "memory efficient".

Comment: @arjungulyani -- C++ has something called "undefined behavior".  It seems you are learning C++ by writing examples, and if it compiles and seems to work, it is valid code.  That is not how C++ works.  There are countless examples of wrong code "working", not just yours.  `Widget *w = new Widget[10]; delete w;` may also "work", but it is undefined behavior to call `delete` on a pointer allocated with `new[]`.  Unlike other computer languages you have been using, you can't be proficient at C++ by writing code that purposefully breaks the rules but just happens to "work".

Comment: Besides the discussion on the pointers and performance, also note that since you are using i as an index for the map, you should initialize it first, either inline or in a constructor.

Comment: @arjungulyani [Your example being run on another compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/a6EK5bG9T).  The output shows exactly what has been stated as to why storing the address of a temporary is wrong.